# With ansible how do I loop over a list and use the items as key to lookup values

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a playbook that gathers name and version numbers of packages and outputs the relevant name and package numbers into a local report. How do I the current item in an iteration over a list, as a key in another item lookup that im parsing with jinja.

```
---
- name: gather facts about packages that are installed on you managed nodes and write a report
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: servers
  vars:
    target_packages:
    - bash
    - kernel
    - glibc
  tasks:
  - name: gather facts
    package_facts:
      manager: rpm
  - name: output the relevant package number into a local file
    defer_to: localhost
    command: echo "{{ ansible_facts.packages['item']['name'] }}"="{{ ansible_facts.packages['item']['name']\>\> logfile
    loop: "{{ target_packages }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, in Ubuntu

```yaml
    - package_facts:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ target_packages }}"
      when: item in ansible_facts.packages
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=bash) => 
  msg:
  - arch: amd64
    category: shells
    name: bash
    origin: ''
    source: apt
    version: 5.0-6ubuntu1.1
skipping: [localhost] => (item=kernel) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=glibc)
```

The items in the dictionary *packages* are lists because there might be installed more versions of the same package. If you want to put the results into files, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "logfile.{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        content: |-
          {% for pkg in target_packages %}
          {% if pkg in ansible_facts.packages %}
          {% for i in ansible_facts.packages[pkg] %}
          {{ i['name'] }} {{ i['version'] }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat logfile.localhost 
bash 5.0-6ubuntu1.1
```

The example above was running at localhost only. The *delegate_to* directive is needed to write the log to localhost when running at remote hosts. You might want to append the name of the host to the logfile. Otherwise, it will be overwritten if there are more hosts in the play.